# Why image view in android don't show updated image from server using Glide libaray?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I am using `Glide Library` to load image on `ImageView` from server, but it show only previous image not updated image.

```
 Glide.with(getActivity()).load(profile_image_link).error(R.drawable.placehoder_user).into(iv_user_image);
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Glide.with(getActivity()).load(profile_image_link).error(R.drawable.placehoder_user).into(iv_user_image); please  check code i have added.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for that issue is Glide caching the image (it still has the previous version of the image in cache).

Try to clear the cache of your app, or uninstall it then reinstall it. You should see the updated image.

If you don't want to use cache do the following when fetching the image:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
    .load(profile_image_link)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .error(R.drawable.placehoder_user)
    .into(iv_user_image)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer  but i need cache , as i don't want to load image again and again